# Can Chronicle Map work on Java 1.6 ? or Below that?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, chronicle, chronicle-map

I have used Chronicle Map in Java 1.7 on My Machine. I wanted to know can I used the same on java 1.6 ? as I have to build and Deploy it on the Server which is running on Java 1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Chronicle Map 2.x's mimimum supported Java version is Java 7, Chronicle Map 3.x's minimum supported version is Java 8.